# Is it possible to retrieve Lotus notes rich text without using Lotus notes api?

Tags: lotus

I need to create a application which receives a lotus note document file . Is it possible to retrieve Lotus notes rich text without using Lotus notes api?

Comment: Are you talking about Java, LotusScript, COM, C-API?

Answer (score 2):

You also can get rich text via http/https, using web API. HTTP task should be turned on to use this method.
Just use a request as follows:
*server/databasefilepath/databasename/viewname/selectionkey/richtextitemname?OpenField*

This will return you rich text item, transformed into html, that is realy userful.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use HTTP task as shiv suggested, you can try this tool by Julian Robichaux  http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#richtexttohtml.

Notes from the author:

> This database has a script library that describes a technique allowing
>   you to get the contents of a regular Rich Text field as MIME/HTML,
>   even if that field isn't set to store contents as MIME.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using Domino XML Language (DXL). This renders an XML style format that you can then work through however it is complex if the user has added lots of bullet points, bolding the odd image etc.

You will have to use  CreateDXLExporter() either in your app or rendered via web from a notes agent however once you have built it, each document will be available to you and in fact the entire database.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Function Disclaimer
On Error GoTo errH
Dim curDb As NotesDatabase
Dim PolicyVw As NotesView
Dim PolicyDoc As NotesDocument
Dim policykey As String
Dim DisclaimerStatus As String
Dim DisclaimText As String
Set session = New NotesSession
Set curDb = session.Currentdatabase
Set PolicyVw = curDb.Getview("Settings")

```
Set PolicyDoc = PolicyVw.GetDocumentBykey("MailDisclaimer")
While Not PolicyDoc Is Nothing
    DisclaimerStatus=PolicyDoc.PolicyDoc(0)
    If DisclaimerStatus="1" Then
        DisclaimText=PolicyDoc.DisclaimText(0)  
    End If
    
    
Wend    

    Exit Function
```

errH:

```
    Print "Error in Disclaimer: "+ CStr(Error())+" at line number "+ CStr(Erl())
    Exit Function
```

End Function